# unexpected token import/export - typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying out typescript for the first time and am confused about the import/export procedures that I am used to using with es6.

this is an interface I am trying to export in a file called `transformedRowInterface.ts`:

```
export interface TransformedRow  {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  summary: string;
  body: string;
  synopsis: string;
  author: object;
  impressions: number;
  created: number;
  updated: number;
}
```

and this is my attempt to import, in a file called `newsArticleModel.ts`:

```
const appRoot = require("app-root-path");

import { TransformedRow } from "./transformedRowInterface";
//throws the error below:
// [Node] /newsArticleModel.ts:2
// [Node] import { TransformedRow } from "./transformedRowInterface";
//SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
// also tried a require below, which also throws an error:
// const transformedRow = require(appRoot + "/src/controllers/transformedRowInterface.ts");
// throws this error: 
// [Node] (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export interface TransformedRow  {
//   [Node]                                                               ^^^^^^
//   [Node]
//   [Node] SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

this is my tsconfig:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      // "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you are targeting `ES2017`, which supports the syntax for imports "out of the box", i.e. your output would literally contain

```
import { thing } from './wotsit';
```

If your runtime doesn't support this kind of import, you will need to use down-level compilation (i.e. target ES5) so the import gets converted into the CommonJS require call.

You can test my theory by looking at the JavaScript output to see what the import looks like.

Comment: that was it, thanks! I changed it to ES2016 and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score -4):

`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export})`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token export.`

If you are getting same problem. May be you are doing 'node .ts' , it should be node .js