# Unexpected token export es6 dependency in ts project

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, ts-node

Im trying to use the library [bpmn.io](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js) in a local type script project in order to extend it.

So i try to import its components using the statement `import {BpmnModeler, BpmnViewer} from 'bpmn-js'`. The library apparently uses es6 modules internally to import and export stuff around.

When i try to run this code using `ts-node <path/to/my/index.ts>` (entry point of my typescript project), i get an unexpected token 'export' in the terminal, at the default export from the bpmn.io library.

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],

    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": [
      "."
    ],

    "esModuleInterop": true,
   
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "references": [],
  "watchOptions": {
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority",
    "excludeDirectories": [
      "**/node_modules",
      "build"
    ]
  }
}
```

I believe this happens because i have `module: "commonjs"` option set in the tsconfig.json above. But if i change it to `module: "es6"` then i must set the `type="module"` option in my package.json which results in *unknonwn file extension .ts* error. Kind of in a circle of problems here

Comment: "*unknonwn file extension .ts*" - but your package.json should reference the compiled .js files, not the typescript sources?

Comment: when im using node, sure. I'm using ts-node though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your target to ES5?

Check this answer:

[unexpected token import/export - typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611503/unexpected-token-import-export-typescript)

I was having the same issue but I fixed it.