# Importing plain JS from TS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to consume some ES6 JavaScript code (so, just a bunch of ES6 files, not a 3rd party library) from a Typescript file, in the context of an Angular app (or library). Given that's a corner usage case, I cannot find much information by googling around (most directions refer to importing JS libraries), except for what I have already done; yet, I'm still having issues.

As a test, I just created a new Angular 13 workspace (`ng new test`), without routing and with plain CSS. Then, I made these changes to its default template:

(1) in `tsconfig.json`, I added `"allowJs": true` ([reference here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs)) to the compiler options. The result is:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

(2) added a dummy JS module under `/src/assets/js/hello.js` with this content:

```js
// just to be explicit, yet strict is implied by export:
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
'use strict';

export const SOME_CONSTANT = 10;

export function sayHello(name) {
  console.log('Hello ' + name);
}
```

(3) included the JS file in the app via `angular.json` (under `architect/build/options/scripts`):

```json
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/js/hello.js"
]
```

(4) imported `sayHello` into `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { sayHello } from 'src/assets/js/hello';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    sayHello('world!');
  }
}
```

(5) added `src/typings.d.ts` to include ambient type declarations, with this content:

```
declare function sayHello(name: string): void;
```

Now, the app builds, and the function gets invoked and outputs its message on the console; but there are a couple of **issues**:

- at runtime I get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`. This would appear to point at a JS script loaded without `type="module"` (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export)), but scripts are loaded via `angular.json` here, so they should already be loaded as modules (as it appears from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22159)). The default value for `module` in `tsconfig` is `es2020`, so [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546632/unexpected-token-export-es6-dependency-in-ts-project) does not seem to apply.
- typings do not seem to be in effect. I can e.g. remove the string argument from `sayHello` and `ng build` succeeds, despite the argument being declared in `types.d.ts` (and of course I get no typed intellisense in VSCode for `sayHello`).

Answer (score 0):

I created a new angular project, without any modifications it works like this for me. Is this what you are looking for? You can also set "noImplicitAny" to false in tsconfig.json and it will work without a d.ts file. [image: example]

Comment: Thank you! So you just added the JS file without any change to config? This seems odd, and does not work for me. Apart from the path (your app.component has src/js/hello but it is rather ../js/hello from that location), I did nothing different, but I get TS2306 hello.d.ts is not a module.